# Return from function fails C++

Tags: c++, qt, smtp

I have a problem and I don't know why is it occurs.
My **Qt** project includes class `AllExceptions`. It has the following constructor:

```
AllExceptions::AllExceptions(std::string errName){
    errorMessage = errName;
} //<<<---
```

I call constructor in the following way:

```
throw AllExceptions(response);
```

where `response` is a string that represents *smtp* server answer.

**Problem:** program stucks at constructing object. I debbuged and figured out that it stucks at point that I marked `<<<---`.
Any advice, please.

EDIT: stack at that point

```
AllExceptions::AllExceptions (this=0xaf47d0, errName={static npos = <optimized out>, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x7fffffffca10 \"\\330;\\257\"}})    
Email::sendMessage (this=0xa2e950)  
NewMailWindow::sendMail (this=0x885bb0) 
NewMailWindow::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x885bb0, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=0, _a=0x7fffffffcdb0) 
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () 
QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) ()   
?? ()   
?? ()   
QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) () 
QWidget::event(QEvent*) ()  
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) ()    
QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()  
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) ()  
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) () 
?? ()   
QApplication::x11ProcessEvent(_XEvent*) ()  
?? ()   
g_main_context_dispatch ()  
?? ()   
g_main_context_iteration () 
QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()   
?? ()   
QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () 
QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()  
QCoreApplication::exec() () 
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe478)
```

Header file:

```
class AllExceptions{
public:
    AllExceptions(std::string errName);
    std::string getErrMess() {return errorMessage;}; 
        void displayError();
private:
    std::string errorMessage;
};
```

Comment: Please show the stack in that point.

Comment: first advice: post more relevant code. Preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Where is `errorMessage` declared? That is a `std::string` too, correct?

Comment: Style note: Idiomatic C++ uses initializer lists, and what's the point of `std::string` in a Qt project? Your constructor should be: `AllExceptions(const QString & msg) : m_errorMessage(msg) {}`.

Comment: @loentar stack trace added

Comment: Are you catching that exception in `NewMailWindow::sendMail`? I can generate an identical stack trace without anything getting stuck.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "stucks"? Does it halt? Does it loop? Does it crash? Do you get any kind of error message?

Comment: @KubaOber yes, i catch exception in `NewMailWindow::sendMail`, but still getting stuck

Comment: @molbdnilo i don't getting error messages. Program is executed without ending

Comment: As it is in all such cases, you need to start cutting stuff out of your program until the problem vanishes. The code that you show is fine and is *not* the source of the problem.

Comment: The only weird thing is the content of the `errName` - `_M_p` looks wrong, but this may be because the argument is being destructed. Please show the line where you construct the `AllExceptions` instance, and any lines prior to it that may be the source of the data you pass to `errName`. My hunch at this point is that you pass junk `std::string` argument.